# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros de un Activity a una clase que hereda de un DialogFragment? Xamarin Android

Tags: android-fragment, xamarin.android

Tengo en un Activity, un list view, que doy click y me tiene que traer un DialogFragment (cómo un PopUp), pero el diseño de ese DialogFragment está en otro axml, y por lo tanto en otra case, pero la otra clase no es de tipo Activity, es de tipo DialogFragment, cómo puedo hacer para pasar parámetros entre ellos?

```
 private void LstEstilos_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            AltaEstilosController metodo = new AltaEstilosController();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog();


        //Región del PopUp
        alert.SetTitle(parametroBorrado);
        alert.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.StatSysUploadDone);
        alert.SetTitle("Actualizar/Eliminar");
        alert.SetPositiveButton("Actualizar ", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {                   
            dialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
            string dato = lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdArticulo.ToString();
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Dialog));
            intent.PutExtra("Id", dato);
            this.StartActivity(intent);


        });
        alert.SetNegativeButton("Eliminar", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {

        });
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            alert.Show();
        });
    }
```

Aquí está la otra clase que hereda de FragmentDialog

```
namespace KobitAndroidBeta
{
    public class Dialog : DialogFragment
    {

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DialogInput , container, false);
            var btnActualiza = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.btnActualizarPopUpEstilo);
            return view;
        }
        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes recibir los parametros por el constructor de tu Dialog:

```
public class Dialog : DialogFragment
{

   private int this.transactionId
        public Dialog(string transactionId)
        {
           this.transactionId =  transactionId;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            //...

            // utilizas el id pasado por el contructor.
            var transacciones =buscarTransaccionesPorId(this.transactionId);

            return view;
        }

}
```

Entonces para invocar el Dialog:

```
 private void LstEstilos_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
        {
          AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         //...

        alert.SetPositiveButton("Actualizar ", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {     
            string dato = lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdArticulo.ToString(); 

              var dialog = new Dialog(dato);

            dialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");            
            //..
        });
```